# PHP/MySQL - Incrementing variable name to loop for data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have rows in my `teams` table named `player1`, `player2`, `player3` ... `player12`. In PHP script i set them as variables (`$player1`,`$player2`...) and want to loop through them to check if they are `NULL`, and if they are not to count them.

How may I increment a variable in PHP? I have tried doing it likes this:

```
<?
    $playerspicked = 0;
    for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        $playercheck = "$player"+$i;
        if($playercheck != 0) {
            $playerspicked++;
        }
    }
?>
```

but this wouldn't work.

Comment: Normalize your data, and then you wouldn't need to use such a dirty solution

Comment: @MarkBaker what do you mean by normalize?

Comment: I mean structure your database tables.... having numbered column names is generally an indication that you should be using a separate table with a row for each player

Comment: A schema like that is a huge violation of the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). If you created a proper relational table this would be trivial. I'd strongly recommend redoing your schema before trying to solve this problem: You'll only fossilize this really awkward design.

Comment: Oh, I probably gave way too little details and got misunderstood. In table named teams there are teams added by users. Player1, 2 etc are just kind of settings, user can pick up to 12 members for his sport team from a predefined list. I'm not storing multiple players data in a single row :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with complex expressions (curly brackets `{}`) around a variable name.

```
if(empty(${"player$i"})) {
    //player$i is empty
}
```

complex expressions allow you to set variable names dynamically.

To help you better understand how these work, I will show you that
you can also use these just like regular string concatenation like so

```
$variable = "many test";
echo "this is a test echo. {$variable}";
```

I commonly use this for generating a variable for many array variables based on their key

```
$array = array("key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2");
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
}
```

The code above would create 2 variables, `$key1` and `$key2`, with the appropriate value associated with them.

Alternatively, I'm pretty sure you can just add another `$` to the front of your variable, but I would say this is harder to read and figure out what's going on.

```
$playercheck = "player"+$i;  
if($$playercheck != 0) {
    $playerspicked++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing these methods, they are of much help!

Answer (score 1):

In your case there is a much easier way to count all the not null players in the team.

echo count(array_filter($yourTeam));

the array_filter function without a second parameter will automatically remove the null entries.

Comment: That seems really simple and effective as well. If I have some more rows in my $team table, for example two that are not players, all I have to do is decrease the count() by 2 with simple arithmetic?